# Free 3D Scene Simulation Framework

Tags: 3d, c++, virtual-reality, scene-description

I want to visualize a scene with simple shapes (e.g. boxes, pyramides, etc.) and I am looking for a tool or framework in C/C++ to do this. Focus of the application is to parameterize the relative coordinates (position+rotation) of the scene objects. Also defined camera view support would be much welcomed. What I actually would want is the VRML World Editor from Simulink. However I need something thats free for company in-house use.

Could anybody give suggest me something suitable?

Comment: Try a game engine like unity, etc... not sure this is the best place for this question though

Comment: Thanks, I have thought of Unity already. But I think it would be overkill for my purpose. I was hoping to find something not so complex.

Comment: if it's really for trivial shapes and to play with positions and orientations, why base OpenGL is not good ?

Comment: Not sure if this is what you're looking for, but [OpenSceneGraph](http://www.openscenegraph.org/) or [Vtk](http://www.vtk.org/) are [scene graph toolkits](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scene_graph). You may want to check licensing. I think they are LGPL but I'm not sure.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe your problem or need and the steps, if any, you've taken to solve it. See also [What topics can I ask about here?](http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)